# How to put Like function under an image and save the "Liked" status?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to figure out how to put a "Like function" to a few local stored images and remember the app that the user liked those images. Let me explain: I want the user to be able to press "Like" under the image he likes. This means the "Liked" status of the image has to be saved somehow (I think through SharedPreferencies). Then I want to make a tableview in another view where it will show first the images the user liked and below the images he didn't actually liked (he just didn't press the button).

The only code I wrote is a simple OnClick code which is this:

```
like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartfull);
            //gotta put here what to do to set the image status to "Liked" 
              and save it so the app will know forever that the user liked it

        }
    });
```

Comment: You need something to identify each image uniquely. Then use one of multiple ways mentioned here to store the status (liked/ not liked etc.): http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't really recommend using SharedPreferences to that extent. To me that feels like that extends in to "abuse" of its intended functionality. Maybe other people having differing opinions on that. I would personally use an SQLite database or something.

However, to answer your question.

When initializing your like button:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

if(sp.getBoolean(unique_image_id, false)){
    like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartfull);
}
```

When you click on the like button.

```
like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
         Boolean liked = !sp.getBoolean(unique_image_id,false);
            sp.edit().putBoolean(unique_image_id, liked).apply();
            if(liked){
            like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartfull);
            }else{
              like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartempty);    
        }
    });
```

A unique id for the image could be its file path or url.